# Why WPF Binding does not invoke propertyChangedCallback defined in PropertyMetadata, while setter in code-behind does?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have made a user control and in it I've defined a dependency property like so:

```cs
public static readonly
DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Source",
        typeof( ObservableCollection<object> ),
        typeof( SingleLineChart ), 
        new PropertyMetadata(
            default( ObservableCollection<object> ),
            lineAffectedPropertyChanged ) );
```

I also have an ordinary property, which wrap the above one. In its setter I just call the `SetValue( SourceProperty, value );` method.

When I set this `Source` from code-behind file the `lineAffectedPropertyChanged` invoked and executed, everything fine; but when I use a simple data-binding nothing happens.

```xml
        <Line:SingleLineChart
        Name="bestFitnessDisplayer"
        Source="{Binding Path=bestFitnessHistory}"
        Margin="20"/>
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Do you get any binding errors? maybe the path bestFitnessHistory isn´t found

Comment: Agree with Jehof. Probably something is wrong with the binding. Where is bestFitnessHistory located? According to your naming style I suspect it to be inside view. But your binding expects this collection inside bound DataContext.

Comment: Another remark: normally it's bad practice to use a default value with collection DependencyProperties: If you do, all objects of the class will use the same collection object as default value, basically sharing the same items. But this has probably nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: nop! no binding errors and I set the proper datacontext at the parent node

Comment: And what is bestFitnessHistory? is it a field/property?
And do you notify the SingleLineChart that whenever you create/modify/fill this property/field somehow?
Or is it a dependency property?
I think the problem here is that you don't assign/create bestFitnessHistory in the contructor of the datacontext but sometimes later and then (if it's a CLR-property) you need to tell the view that it changed.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late.
I guess the generic Type of the bound property is not of type object.
.Net can't convert between types of `ObservableCollection<object>` and `ObservableCollection<Something>` . It is better to create a DependencyProperty of type IEnumerabe/ICollection or IList without generic parameters.